# Listen to Browser Push Notifications in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, twitter

I am trying to listen to my Twitter Browser Notifications using NodeJS so that I can be alerted as to when there is a new tweet. How would I go about finding the Websocket url that Chrome is currently using to subscribe to my user notifications and go about connecting to it?

Currently Twitter charges $5k a month to stream tweets, I'm trying to figure out how to get notified of new tweets and then fetch them using the regular $100 a month Basic package. If anyone has a better way to acheive this, feel free to mention.